# ng-repeat iterating over only the first item

Tags: angularjs, pug

main file:

body

```
#major(ng-controller='AppCtrl', ng-init="set_riddleTypes(#{JSON.stringify(riddleTypes)}); set_riddleDB(#{JSON.stringify(riddleDB)})")
  #riddlrHead.accordionButton
    .riddlrName Riddlr
    .profile1
      span
        a(href='#') #{user.name}
      p
        a(href='#') #{user.solveCount} riddles, #{user.points} points
    .profile_round
  #mainBody.accordionContent
    #foodOptions
      br
      br
      span What would you like to eat?
      ul
        li(ng-repeat="riddleType in riddleTypes")
          {{riddleType}}
```

AppCtrl file:

```
function AppCtrl($scope){

    $scope.set_riddleTypes = function(riddleTypes){
        $scope.riddleTypes = riddleTypes;
    };

    $scope.set_riddleDB = function(riddleDB){
        $scope.riddleDB = riddleDB;
    }
}
```

the riddletypes list contains 14 items. If I just display riddletypes, it shows the whole list but ng-repeat only iterates over the first item. Any idea why?

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log($scope.riddleTypes)` inside the `set_riddleTypes` function?

Comment: It shouldn't be undefined

Comment: I have initialized $scope.riddleTypes to an emptylist. It now returns []